# Modifying Check Pods Manifest.lock script in build phases of Xcode

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

pod install adds a script to the build phases to check for the Manifest.lock file. It throws an error if the sandbox is not in sync and exits the process. Is there any way to modify this script such that on error I want to perform "pod install".

Comment: Did you ever solve? I am curious about this as well.

Comment: @CharltonProvatas I tried tweaking but ran into some issue. If you want I can post what I have tried.

Comment: That would be helpful.  I had some success by implementing the 'post_install' hook in the Podfile but still wasn't working 100%